# WINAPI WcmSetProperty Fails When Setting wcm_global_property_minimize_policy

Tags: windows

I'm trying to set wcm_global_property_minimize_policy through the WcmSetProperty API. For some reason, the call returns error 87 (Invalid Parameter). The strange thing is I can query this policy through WcmQueryProperty successfully. I have tried to find sample code in the Windows 8 SDK, but AFAIL there are no samples that change global properties.

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong in the following code?

```
void __cdecl main()
{
 DWORD dwRetCode = NO_ERROR;
 DWORD dwSize = 0;
 WCM_POLICY_VALUE policyVal; 
 WCM_POLICY_VALUE *outVal;

 /* Disable Minimize Connections */
 policyVal.fIsGroupPolicy = false;
 policyVal.fValue = false;

 dwSize = sizeof(policyVal);

 wprintf(L"Disabling global property - minimize connections... dwSize: %u\n", dwSize);

 dwRetCode = WcmSetProperty(NULL, NULL, wcm_global_property_minimize_policy, NULL, dwSize, (PBYTE)&policyVal);

 if (dwRetCode == ERROR_SUCCESS) {
  wprintf(L"Disable global property minimize connections is success\n");
 }
 else {
  wprintf(L"Disable global property minimize connections failed\n");
  wprintf(L"Error code: %u\n", dwRetCode);
 }

 dwRetCode = WcmQueryProperty(NULL, NULL, wcm_global_property_minimize_policy, NULL, &dwSize, (PBYTE *)&outVal);

 if ((dwRetCode == ERROR_SUCCESS) /*&& (p2Data != NULL)*/) {
  wprintf(L"Global property minimize policy is: %d.%d with size %d\n", outVal->fIsGroupPolicy, outVal->fValue, dwSize);
 }
 else {
  wprintf(L"Error in querying property - minimize policy \n");
  wprintf(L"Error code: %u\n", dwRetCode);
 }
}
```

Also, if I change wcm_global_property_minimize_policy through WcmSetProperty (), will this require a system reboot before the changed setting goes into effect?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a response from an MSDN forum:

"When calling WcmSetProperty, the documentation specifies that the type of data stored in the pbData should be WCM_POLICY_VALUE.

This appears to be an error in the documentation.  For setting wcm_global_property_minimize_policy, set pbData as type BOOL and the call should succeed."